# Quick question: can a function send multiple tokens?

Tags: solidity, ether, tokens, erc-20

And by the question I mean if I can send a couple of few different ERC20's or let's say even 1 ERC20 + some amount of ether in one function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both of these things by using a smart contract. The limitation you will run into here is the amount of gas being used for this transaction.

If you want to send many ERC20 tokens, you would use the following code in your smart contract:

```
ERC20Interface(ERC20Token0).transfer(to_address, value);
ERC20Interface(ERC20Token1).transfer(to_address, value);
ERC20Interface(ERC20Token2).transfer(to_address, value);
```

If you want to transfer an ERC20 token and Ether, you would do:

```
ERC20Interface(ERC20Token0).transfer(to_address, value);
to_address.transfer(value);
```

There is other code that needs to be inserted into the smart contract, but those are the critical pieces.

Comment: I do just what you said but I keep getting the following error in Remix while sending the transaction: https://imgur.com/a/k1dMOqr

Comment: Are you sending ETH or a token?

Comment: 1 token and some amount of ether

Comment: Try commenting out each line to see where the error is occurring. Try to just send ETH first, and then if that works you know it is the token that is failing. Note: for that transaction to work, you must have sent ETH into the smart contract. It cannot pull from your wallet. So you would have to have already sent ETH into the contract initially.

Comment: I've followed what you said and it turned out that my ERC20 interface had a little error. I had it as

`function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);`
and removing the return statement solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it.